# Given an IP address, find interface on same subnet

Tags: linux, bash, ethernet

I'm trying to create a bash script and a small part of it requires figuring out if, given an IP address of another computer, what interface is on that same network.

So if my computer is has the following interfaces (not including lo):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX
          inet addr:192.168.5.100  Bcast:192.168.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

and I know that there is a computer at the following address:

```
192.168.0.101
```

is there a simple way to extract the answer `eth0`?

P.S. This question is **NOT** asking about getting the the interface given the address of my own computer like [this post is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986169/how-can-i-fetch-the-ethernet-port-given-the-ip-address).

Comment: Loop through the interfaces, and mask both the interface IP and the given IP with the interface's subnet mask. If the results are equal, they're on the same subnet. Please show what you've tried, we're not here to do your work for you, just help you fix what you wrote.

Comment: Isn't routing tables more reliable for your case? You may check information with that simple command: `ip route get DESTADDR`

Comment: Which in itself brings up a good point. If you are parsing `ifconfig`, you may want to move to parsing the output of `ip` as `ifconfig` will go away after transition to `systemd` is complete. `ifconfig` will only be available on a distro-by-distro basis. It no longer exists on `Arch`.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I realized I lied to you. The computer I'm looking for doesn't exist yet. I'm actually working with an embedded system that I need to assign the IP address to. `ip route get DESTADDR` unfortunately gave me the wrong answer (I assume because it used the wirelesses default gateway). I was hoping to have to avoid using messy subnet parsing code, but maybe I can't.

Comment: If `ip route get` gave you the wrong information then how are you expecting the route to work later? Are you adding an ip on the network on a (possibly new) device so that it will be used in routing decisions for that IP later?

Comment: Assigning the IP to the embedded system through a serial port.

Answer (score 0):

no, the name `eth0` is not broadcasted in any way, so there is no way to get it remotely. it is just a name that is only internally used.
You'd have to log into the remote machine (ssh) and get the info using for example `ifconfig`.

if you need the macaddress of the remote machine (on your network) use arp:

```
arp 192.168.0.101
```

Comment: Sure there is a way, you calculate `IP Addr & netmask` for each interface and check if that's equal to `192.168.0.101 & netmask`.

Comment: @nos no, that doesn't help any way to figure out if it is eth0, eth1, wlan0,... as was stated in the original question.

Comment: Indeed there is no way to discover how a host call an interface configured with an specific IP, another similar option would be to use some inventory service where all the hosts register their interfaces and IPs, you could query this service for this information. But if you don't have access to the remote host, then there is no way to do it.

Comment: I believe you have misinterpreted my question. I am trying to ask "Given a random IP address, does my computer have a NIC with an IP address assigned to the same subnet?"

Comment: @lxer  Sure there are caveats if you have multiple nics on the same subnet. But comparing network addresses is the canonical way to check if one IP address belongs to a particular subnet, and is (excluding any odd iptables or routing rules you've added) what the IP stack will do to figure out which interface to use when sending to the destination IP. e. in  this case `eth0: 192.168.0.100 & 255.255.255.0 == 192.168.0.0`,`wlan0: 192.168.5.100&255.255.255.0 == 192.168.5.0`. Calculating the subnet for 192.168.0.101 against each of the netmasks, you'll find that the network address matches eth0